# Find amount of heads and tails from percentages

Tags: code-golf

**Note: as this question has been marked as a duplicate, I have accepted an answer. However, I will still check this question if users can find a shorter way of doing it, and accept that answer.**

Given two numbers (which are multiples of `0.5`) representing `heads-percentage` and `tails-percentage` from a series of coin-flipping, output the *minimum* amounts of heads and tails to produce percentages such as those. Input and output can be in any form. However, output must be in a readable format (Good examples are `x y`, `[x y]`, etc).

Examples:

- Input: `25 75` (25% heads, 75% tails) Output: `1 3` (an output of `25 75` is invalid since that is not the *minimum* amounts of heads and tails to produce those percentages)
- Input: `30 70` (30% heads, 70% tails) Output: `3 7`
- Input: `99.5 0.5` (99.5% heads, 0.5% tails) Output: `199 1`

You may assume that there will always be a digit before and after a decimal point in an input (no `.5`s or `15.`s). You may also assume the input adds up to 100%. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Can the numbers be taken as a list? As two number inputs?

Comment: @xnor either is fine

Comment: Would `[199.0, 1.0]` a valid output for the last example?

Comment: @Dennis yes it would.

Comment: This might effectively be the same as [simplifying a fraction](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35587/20260). My [answer there](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35652/20260) is basically the same as here except for input processing.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a dupe of the question xnor linked or whether it's a continued fractions question similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17239/194 or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26278/194 which requires finding the simplest fraction which *rounds* to the given input.

Comment: Also similar to [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5595/4020).

Comment: And the BigRational datatype in my Java library is set up to simplify the fraction automatically in the constructor.

Comment: @xnor it is defined similar, but I dont think it is close enough to close.

Comment: If the total adds up to 100%, why not accept a single number input 0 <= x <= 100?

Comment: @JArkinstall that is a good thought, but it is much too late now as 9 people would have to change their answers and it is not a good idea to change spec after this many people answered.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it is changed - I was just wondering if there's a specific reason. Aaaand now this has been closed as a dupe, so that's my half-baked Haskell attempt lost in the sands of time.

Comment: @JArkinstall I just did not think of it at first, now thinking about it though, it would of prevented a 3 byte answer... oh well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, 3 bytes

```
,÷∨
```

This is a dyadic function train that accepts the percentages as left and right arguments:

```
┌─┼─┐
, ÷ ∨
```

It is equivalent to the following, train-less function:

```
{(⍺,⍵)÷⍺∨⍵}
```

Try it online on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=99.5%28%2C%F7%u2228%290.5&run).

#### How it works

```
  ∨  Compute the GCD of both arguments.
,    Concatenate both arguments.
 ÷   Divide the latter by the former.
```

Comment: There is literally no way this can be beaten. Excellent job! :D

Comment: I really should learn this language, it looks fascinating.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 2, 47 bytes

```python
A,B=a,b=input()
while b:a,b=b,a%b
print A/a,B/a
```

Takes input like `15,20` and prints the output like `3 4`.

Performs the Euclidian algorithm to find the gcd, then scales the numbers by it.

Fortunately, Python will happily compute `%` on fractions, so inputs like `0.5 99.5` behave just the same. More type-strict languages (cough, Haskell) aren't so lucky.

Comment: Also, floats are annoying in Haskell. `20/100*5` is not equal to `20/100 + 20/100 + 20/100 + 20/100 + 20/100`, which is what is put in lists like `[0,20/100..]`

Answer (score 7):

## J, 4 bytes

```
,%+.
```

Explanation:

```
       (x +. y)     NB. GCD of the left and right inputs
      %             NB. divided by
(x, y)              NB. a vector consisting of the inputs
```

[Try it online](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=99.5%20(%2C%25%2B.)%200.5)

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>25</s> 14 bytes

```
{_~{_@\%}h;f/}
```

This is an unnamed function that pops a list from the stack and leaves one in return. Like @xnor's answer, it uses the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD, then divides the list elements by it.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%0A%20%20%7B_~%7B_%40%5C%25%7Dh%3Bf%2F%7D%0A~p&input=%5B99.5%200.5%5D).

#### How it works

```
_             Push a copy of the input array.
 ~            Dump its elements on the stack.
  {    }h     Do:
   _            Push a copy of the topmost integer.
    @           Rotate the bottom-most integer on top of it.
     \          Swap them.
      %         Calculate the residue of their division.
              While the residue is positive, repeat the loop.
         ;    Discard the last residue (0).
              This leaves the GCD on the stack.
          f/  Divide the elements of the input array by their GCD.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
J/R.5Q/RiFJJ
```

Like @xnor's answer, this divides each list item by their GCD. Pyth has the GCD as a built-in, but it doesn't work for floats out of the box.

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%2FR.5Q%2FRiFJJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B25%2C+75%5D%0A%5B30%2C+70%5D%0A%5B99.5%2C+0.5%5D&debug=0)

#### How it works

```
              (implicit) Save the evaluated input in Q.
 /R.5Q        Divide each element of Q by 0.5.
              This transforms the array's floats into integers.
J             Save the result in J.
        iFJ   Compute the GCD of the elements of J.
      /R   J  Divide the elements of J by their GCD.
```

Comment: Since the numbers are multiples of 0.5, could you multiply the inputs by 2, and then use the integer GCD?

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing. `/R.5` divides by 0.5, casting to integer in the process.

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sense. From the description I got the impression that you might not be using the built-in GCD, and went for the Euclid algorithm instead.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 20 bytes

```
{⍺⍵÷⍺{0<⍵:⍵∇⍵|⍺⋄⍺}⍵}
```

This creates an unnamed dyadic function that accepts the inputs on the left and right and returns an array. Unlike Dennis' super slick [Dyalog solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62065/20469), this works with other versions of APL because it doesn't use trains and it doesn't assume that GCD (`∨`) works for floats.

Explanation:

```
    ⍺{0<⍵:⍵∇⍵|⍺⋄⍺}⍵}   ⍝ Compute the GCD of the inputs using the Euclidean algorithm
{⍺⍵÷                   ⍝ Divide the inputs by their GCD
```

[Try all test cases online](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B%u237A%u2375%F7%u237A%7B0%3C%u2375%3A%u2375%u2207%u2375%7C%u237A%u22C4%u237A%7D%u2375%7D%u22C425%20f%2075%u22C430%20f%2070%u22C499.5%20f%200.5&run)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
#/GCD@@Rationalize@#&
```

Another program with the same byte count is

```
#/GCD@@(Floor[2#]/2)&
```

Mma has never supported FP well...

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>31</s> <s>22</s> 24 bytes

Forgot to count new lines before...

```
Prompt A,B  
gcd(2A,2B➡C 
Disp 2A/C,2B/C
```

This was done in the middle of math class...

Comment: You can skip the closing parenthesis in the third line.

Comment: And you can use `Disp` instead of `Output` to save about 8 bytes.

Comment: Also, chainging the top two lines to 'Prompt A,B' might help.

Comment: You can use the implicit Disp at the end if you output as a list: `2/C{A,B`.

Comment: If you also take input as a list from Ans there's an 11 byte solution: `2Ans/min(gcd(2Ans,min(2Ans`

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>168</s> 94

```
(let((x(floor(*(read)2)))(y(floor(*(read)2))))(format t "~A ~A"(/ x(gcd x y))(/ y(gcd y x))))
```

I missed the original bit about everything being a multiple of 0.5 (thanks xnor!), so this is a good bit shorter than my first go (Gotta' love that almost a third of those bytes are parentheses.)

Comment: You're guaranteed the inputs are multiples of 0.5, so doubling suffices to make them whole.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice that. I'll shorten this answer right quick, thanks.